# Modify the registration page in the membership entity module

Tags: hooks

I am new to drupal.  I would like to remove some of the fields on the registration page of the Membership Entity module and add others.  The new fields that I add need to be saved into the database.  I think I can do this with alter hook but I haven't had success.  Can someone post a code example of how to do this?